# Merge [naming] with [terminology]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I just found out we have a [naming](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag which has 7 questions. 5 of 7 questions would be appropriately tagged by [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) instead. The remaining 2 have to do with file names and layer names, which other tags can cover. Should we delete the naming tag or merge it with [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) (removing it from the 2 questions where that doesn't apply)?

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: Let's! And let's meet the character minimum for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question and my comment received plenty of upvotes, and no one raised any concerns, I went ahead and merged the tags. The [naming](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag is no longer and is now a synonym of [terminology](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology).

Comment: Right right! Done and done.